# php html render ignores styles

Tags: php, html, css

I am gonna try to explain this as best as possible. i have the following varibles

$name = main channel and $childs = sub channels, if i remove the childs from the HTML the main channel shows and not the sub channels, which is correct. but when i try to style the sub channels as a different color then the main it wont allow it, and if you notice i have 2 different images but it ignores the sub channel image and uses the main and only uses. I don't understand how i can remove the sub channel without any affect on the main channel, but but when i try to add a separate icon and css to the sub it ignores it completely.

```
private function renderChannels($channelId)
        {
            $content = "";
            $imagePath = $this->imagePath;
            foreach ($this->_channelDatas as $channel)
            {
                if($channel["pid"] == $channelId)
                {
                    if($channel["show"])
                    {
                        $name = $this->toHTML($channel["channel_name"]);
                        $title = $name  . " [" . $channel["cid"] . "]"; 

                        $link = "javascript:tsstatusconnect('" . $this->_javascriptName . "'," . $channel["cid"] . ")";                 

                        $users = $this->renderUsers($channel["cid"]);
                        $childs = $this->renderChannels($channel["cid"]);


                        $cid = $channel["cid"];

                        $content .= <<<HTML
            <div class="comms-row comms-row-title">  
            <img src="resources/media/icons/sub_channel_icon.png">$name
            <div class="comms-row-flags">$flags</div>
            $users
     <div class="comms-row"><img src="resources/media/icons/sub_channel_icon.png">$childs</div>
    </div>  
    HTML;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us CSS !important on duplicate declarations in the sub-channels. I've noticed the newer updates on Fire fox ignores declarations that are re-declared later. I don't know why. !important will work, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Zaper127 I have tried that i have tried everything using span ids divs nothing works

Comment: do you happen to have an inline style on the element? or set something with javascript that overrides it?

Comment: Zaper127 no i dont also the sub channel image is ignored by the main title image it seems to only render the sub channels exactly as the main channel

Comment: is the style for the main channel in the same style sheet and above the sub channel style? and maybe double check the declarations and make sure you didn't for get a ';' or something.

Comment: Zaper127 double checked everything.

Comment: do you have a live page that I can see to look out the code output?

Comment: but the image still only uses 1